# What is the best way to share variables between a large number of classes?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm using Java to do some complicated calculations, and have a lot of classes that need access to a lot of the same variables. These variables are set at different stages of the calculations, in different classes. The problem is that my code is getting quite messy as I am being forced to pass the same parameters to a lot of different methods.

I am looking for peoples thoughts on what the best approach here would be? One idea I have is to make a superclass with all these variables set in it and extend this class everywhere it is needed.

Another option is to pass an object holding all this information around from method to method but this seems overly complex.
Neither of these solutions feel like the cleanest approach to me. Any thoughts or suggestions of design patterns/ideas that may help me are appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using lots of global variables makes it even more messy.

Comment: this variables are `final` ?

Comment: Question is primary opinion-based. Without exact information about your environment and architecture there is no "one" answer. => Vote for close.

Comment: @Marcinek I think this is a bit unfair. Surely every question is going to generate different opinions. Even if this was a question about a block of code, any response is going to be an opinion. I feel the responses I am getting here are useful and helpful to me. Is this not what stackoverflow is for?

Comment: Best practices are not opinions.

Comment: Finding the best practice is a matter of opinion. As you can see from the answers there is no "best" practice to do it but a practice for a given problem. First one is entirely opinion based. Therefore this question is to be closed until it has been updated to match a concrete problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest that using a `Wrapper` object is the best way to do this. Make sure all fields are immutable (`final` keyword in Java). Use a `Builder` or `Prototype` pattern to create new objects to return.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Singleton? That way you'd have global access to it without passing any instances around and all the variables will be under one roof reducing messiness.

Comment: This would make it necessary to be _very_ sure that you reset the Singleton properly, to not re-use older calculation values.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to be careful, and I don't even know if it fits the use case (i.e. maybe the OP would like two sets of variables), but if it does then it would work.

Comment: How is a Singleton any different from a bunch of global variables?

Comment: It's the same in that it is in global scope, it's different in that all variables are encapsulated within one object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but not sure if a singleton will solve this problem, as the variables I am setting are not all being done at once. They are done at different stages as the calculations progress, so I need more flexibility than the singleton pattern would offer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand to separate the problem world (i.e. the variables) from the algorithms (i.e. calculations) in separate classes. The algorithms would get passed in the problem world, and modify it accordingly. This can be seen as an implementation of the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Depending on the complexity (number of variables, number of algorithms, uncernity of solution path), you could also implement a Black Board Architecture. But I think that would be an overkill, if you're not doing something in artificial intelligence...

Answer (score 0):

If there are a lot of values to be passed around, perhaps an in-memory database would be an appropriate solution. A lot of databases these days offer an in-memory engine, e.g. [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/memory-storage-engine/).

Answer (score -2):

Make a superclass of subclasses then refer to those subclasses of the superclass everytime you need to pull information